# Bash: using sed to replace block of code, treating indents

Tags: bash, sed

There's a file, code looks like that:

```
{
    "name": {
    "port": 4466,
    "host": "localhost",
    "appPort": 3555,
    "abc": {
        "defg": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 5500,
            "userName": "test",
            "password": "test"
        }
    },


    "name2": {
    "port": 4321,
    "host": "localhost",
    "appPort": 1234,
    "abc": {
        "defg": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 5500,
            "userName": "test",
            "password": "test"
        }
    },
```

etc.

I need to replace the following block of code in a file using sed (or maybe awk):

```
"name": {
    "port": 4466,
    "host": "localhost",
    "appPort": 3555
```

Here's what I have, did not succeed:

```
confSearch='"name": {\n        "port": 4466,\n        "host": "localhost",\n        "appPort": 3555'

confReplacement='"name": {\n        "port": 4466,\n        "host": "10.20.30.40",\n        "appPort": 3555'

sed -i "s|$confSearch|$confReplacement|g" "$configFile"
```

Then I tried the following (to search from "name" to "3555" and then replace it):

```
sed -i "/name.*/ {N; s/name.*3555\./$confReplacement/g}" "$configFile"
```

I don't receive any error, the search text is simply not found. I suppose, that's because of indents. How to treat indents correctly? Or should I prefer something else? Taking into account only bash, not perl.

Would be grateful for the help.

Comment: in example you showed you need to change only ipaddress, why do you want to change the whole block?

Comment: Because in the file there are several rows containing "host", and the number of rows is not constant.

Comment: i showed you how t do it in the answer using sed as you asked

Comment: In what answer exactly? Don't see an answer from you.

Comment: I've deleted my answer long ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise against using sed for this task; JSON is not a line-based format, and sed is ill-equipped to handle it unless you are very certain that the file will always be formatted just the right way. There are tools out there that parse JSON properly and work on the object it encodes, so indentation or swapped lines or having several nodes on the same line does not faze them.

In this particular case, I'd suggest jq:

```
jq 'if .name.port == 4466 and .name.appPort == 3555 and .name.host == "localhost" then .name.host="10.20.30.40" else . end' "$configFile"
```

Comment: Thank you. Firstly tried it, and it's really good for JSON, although it's not suitable for me now to install smth third-party. Thus it was implemented in JS in another place, and bash script now just calls JS parser and handler to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/"port": 4466,/,/"host": "localhost",/ s/localhost/110.20.30.40/' "$configFile"
```

assuming there is only 1 host with port 4466

Answer (score 0):

it seems you just want to replace the host, won't you? use something like

`sed -i 's/"host":.*$/"host": "10.20.30.40"\n/'`.

Comment: The thing is that there are several rows containing "host", and the number of rows is not constant.